# JEE MDB with Kafka consumer throws .KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer when deploying

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-kafka

I'm playing with Kafka and how to implement a consumer in a JEE Message Bean.

But when I try to deploy my consumer I receive the following error (in my payara log)

```
 Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
java.lang.Exception
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainer.<init>(MessageBeanContainer.java:221)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainerFactory.createContainer(MessageBeanContainerFactory.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:334)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:570)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:588)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:552)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:582)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:574)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:573)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:120)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1879)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1755)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:294)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:136)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:475)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:397)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:356)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:823)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:664)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:645)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:625)
    at fish.payara.cloud.connectors.kafka.inbound.KafkaAsynchWorker.<init>(KafkaAsynchWorker.java:112)
    at fish.payara.cloud.connectors.kafka.inbound.KafkaResourceAdapter.endpointActivation(KafkaResourceAdapter.java:107)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:207)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer is not an instance of org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:403)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:434)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:419)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:708)
    ... 76 more
]]
```

My platform is:
Payara Server 5.2021.10 #badassfish (build 879)
Java 17

I have followed some tutorials

My Producer:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata;

public class Producer implements Runnable {

    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer;
    String topic = null;

    public Producer() {
        Properties consumerProps = new Properties();
        consumerProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,  "localhost:9092");
        consumerProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        consumerProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        producer = new KafkaProducer<>(consumerProps);
        topic = System.getenv().getOrDefault("TOPIC_NAME", "emails");

    }

    static Random rnd = new Random();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Producing to topic "+ topic);
        while (true) {
            String key = "";
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord(topic, "key-" + rnd.nextInt(10), "val-" + rnd.nextInt(10)), new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata rm, Exception excptn) {
                    System.out.println("Sent data....");
                }
            });
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000); //take it easy!
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Producer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

And my consumer:

```
import fish.payara.cloud.connectors.kafka.api.KafkaListener;
import fish.payara.cloud.connectors.kafka.api.OnRecord;
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;

@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "clientId", propertyValue = "mailClient"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "groupIdConfig", propertyValue = "mailGroup"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "topics", propertyValue = "emails"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "bootstrapServersConfig", propertyValue = "localhost:9092"),    
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "autoCommitInterval", propertyValue = "100"),    
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "retryBackoff", propertyValue = "1000"),    
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "keyDeserializer", propertyValue = "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"),    
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "valueDeserializer", propertyValue = "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"),    
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "pollInterval", propertyValue = "30000"),    
})
public class KafkaMDB implements KafkaListener {
    
    public KafkaMDB() {
        
    }
    
    @OnRecord( topics={"emails"})
    public void test(ConsumerRecord<Object,Object> record) {
        System.out.println("Payara Kafka MDB record " + record );
    }
    
}
```

I can't see what the problem is.

I have installed the kafka-rar-0.7.0 before deploying my consumer and it goes without problems.

Kim

Comment: Seems like a classpath error; I would *guess* that Kafka's client jars are deployed with your application, while the system finds them in the rar (???), which is loaded by a different classloader hence the "*StringDeserializer is not an instance of Deserializer*" error.

Comment: Thank you for your feed back. I will look into that and see if that is the problem. It sounds like a possible problem.